# Можно ли сказать: "Перманентно занят"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, выбор-слов

Можно ли так говорить: "Перманентно занят"?

Comment: Я считаю,что так нельзя говорить.

Answer (score 3):

[Перманентно](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE) - непрерывно, постоянно.
Перманентно занят - непрерывно, постоянно занят.

По-моему, так говорить можно, хотя такая фраза звучит вычурно (почему бы не выразиться стандартным образом: постоянно занят?).

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

*перманентно во хмелю. [Евгений Додолев. Пить или не пить? // «Однако», 2009]*

*Не видал я блаженных! Они перманентно счастливы. Афина. [Георгий Владимов. Шестой солдат (1970-1981)]*

Answer (score 3):

В отличие от Викисловаря в [**толковом словаре Ефремовой**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/213100/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE) слово "перманентно" не относится к книжным:

**перманентно**
*нареч.качеств.-обстоят.* Продолжаясь постоянно, непрерывно.
[От прилагательного *перманентный* (французское *permanent*, от латинского *permaneo* — остаюсь, продолжаюсь), непрерывно продолжающийся, постоянный.]

**Синонимы**: всегда, непрерывно, постоянно, хронически, стойко.

*Перманентно накапливать коллекцию.

Перманентно пополнять запас знаний.*

*Способами хранения коллекции моей я постоянно бываю неудовлетворён, перманентно ищу новых приёмов сбережения собранных мною рисунков.*
А. Сидоров. Записки собирателя

Да, наречие не повседневное (частота употребления слова «перманентно» составляет 103 раза на ≈ 300 млн. слов); но словосочетание "перманентно занят" вполне себе имеет место, хотя и звучит неестественно и манерно.